# Porting WebSphere code to get remote credentials to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere, single-sign-on

I have been asked to look into porting some code from a web app under IBM WAS 7 so that it will run under Tomcat 7.

This is part of a larger SPNEGO/Kerberos SSO system but for purposes of discussion I have distilled the code down to the following that shows the dependencies on the two WebSphere classes AccessController and WSSubject:

```
GSSCredential clientCreds = (GSSCredential) com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
    public Object run() {
        javax.security.auth.Subject subject = com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.getCallerSubject();
        GSSCredential clientCreds = (GSSCredential) subject.getPrivateCredentials(GSSCredential.class).iterator().next();
        return clientCreds;
    }
});
```

I'd like to be able to do this in Tomcat.

[edit]
I think the distilled code above perhaps doesn't explain clearly what is needed. I don't need to configure Tomcat to control access to the web app, nor do I need to impersonate the remote user. What I actually need is the unencrypted Kerberos ticket so that I can pass it to another process that will complete the authentication. Here is a more complete snippet:

```
com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
  public Object run() {
    Oid krb5Mechanism = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
    Oid krb5PrincipalNameType = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2.1");
    GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
    GSSName serverName = manager.createName("HOST/my.host.org", krb5PrincipalNameType);
    javax.security.auth.Subject subject = com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.getCallerSubject();
    GSSCredential clientCreds = (GSSCredential) subject.getPrivateCredentials(GSSCredential.class).iterator().next();
    GSSContext secContext = manager.createContext(serverName, krb5Mechanism, clientCreds, GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);
    // After this the Kerberos ticket is extracted from secContext, converted to a String and passed to the other process for authentication
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What this code basically does is extracting credentials from (presumably) previously authenticated JAAS subject. In the context of Tomcat there is nothing useful in it, since it is only a server-specific way to handle part of SSO.

You should learn how Kerberos-based SSO is implemented for Tomcat. According to [Windows Authentication How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html) this is possible. I did not try this myself however.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify what I am after. The authentication is to be done by another process not Tomcat. I really just need to extract the Kerberos ticket to pass to that process. I have added some more example code to my question that will hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: It is still not clear what part requests ticket from KDC in your scheme and how does the ticket gets into JAAS subject. I guess it is in the form of credentials, but what exactly is that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know as it's not my area of expertise. The best advice I have had so far from the WAS experts I know is that the WAS classes are in some way special and there is no equivalent way of getting to the Windows credentials in Tomcat, so I have been asked to not pursue this further. Many thanks for your interest all the same.